Binary Classification with Three Classes with XGBoost
I am doing binary classification with a signal dataset and two background datasets (call them Background 1 and Background 2). I am currently labeling the signal as 1 and both backgrounds as 0 for binary classification. However, after the binary classification is performed, I want to be able to manipulate the two sources of background separately (for example, plotting them separately), which I can't do if both backgrounds have the same label. What is the best way to label three classes while still performing binary classification?
train = xgb.DMatrix(data=data_train[feature_names], label=data_train.label, missing=-999, feature_names=feature_names, weight=data_train.Weight)
test = xgb.DMatrix(data=data_test[feature_names], label=data_test.label, missing=-999, feature_names=feature_names, weight=data_test.Weight)

param = {}
param['eta']=0.1
param['max_depth']=10
param['subsample']=0.8
param['colsample_bytree']=0.8

param['objective']='binary:logistic'
param['eval_metric']='error'
param=list(param.items()) + [('eval_metric', 'logloss')] + [('eval_metric', 'rmse')]

num_trees=100

booster = xgb.train(param,train,num_boost_round=num_trees)

I have found the sklearn wrapper called OneVsRestClassifier. However, this seems like overkill since it performs all possible permutations of binary classification among the three datasets, which is not what I want (for example, I don't need Background 1 to be separated from Signal + Background 2).
